# Comparing two files in python, with each file having duplicate data

Tags: python, compare, file-handling

I am trying to compare two files in python, its actually trying to find new warnings after comparing it with the old warning file.

The content of the old file is something like this:

```
warning1~file1
warning1~file1
warning2~file2
warning2~file2
warning2~file2
```

and content of the new file is something like this

```
warning1~file1
warning1~file1
warning1~file1
warning3~file3
warning2~file2
warning2~file2
warning2~file2
```

As u can see, in the new file i have 2 new line of text warning1~file1 warning3~file3, i searched for comparing two files over the internet but everywhere they assume that every line of text is different.

```
small_file = open('file1','r')
long_file = open('file2','r')
output_file = open('newfile','w')

try:
    small_lines = small_file.readlines()
    small_lines_cleaned = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in small_lines]
    long_lines = long_file.readlines()
    long_lines_cleaned = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in long_lines]

    #for line in long_lines_cleaned:
    for line in long_lines_cleaned:
        if line not in small_lines_cleaned:
            output_file.writelines(line)
```

I tried this code which i found here, but after running it, realized that it also just checks whether a line from file1 is available in file2 or not. If not, then write to a new file.
This method only fetches warning3, not the new warning1.

I need something where every line is compared only once... and the lines which are left are written to the new file.

I hope i have explained the problem properly.

Comment: Do you want to check if the files are equal or you want the difference as well?

Comment: I just want all the new lines of text that appear in the new file.

Comment: Well I've removed my answer as it didn't help you much.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Others may have liked your answer probably, anyways its upto you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `Counter` to find the difference in the number of occurances, e.g.:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('file2', 'r') as f2, open('newfile', 'w') as output:
    f1_lines = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in f1.readlines()]
    f2_lines = [line.rstrip().lower() for line in f2.readlines()]
    diff = Counter(f2_lines) - Counter(f1_lines)
    for msg, n in diff.iteritems():
        output.writelines((msg + '\n') * n)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Though initially i was confused what Counter was doing but after going through its tutorial, I am pretty clear about its working now. Thanks.

Just another query, can i get the line number of the lines which were fetched from the file with this operation?

Comment: I'm afraid not, and bear in mind that Counter is a sub-class of a dict, so is unsorted as well.

Comment: Hmmm, that would be a bit of trouble, anyways thanks for helping. :)

Comment: Just one more thing, in Python 3, iteritems wasn't working so i used items in its place.

Comment: Good point, items now has the same behaviour as iteritems used to. I'm still stuck in 2.7 land so always forget to mention it :)

Comment: I liked this answer. I didnt know that we can use set/arithmetic operations on dicts also

Comment: @thefourtheye, just to clarify, you can't use arithmetic operations on normal dicts, since they can contain arbitrary values, which may or may not support the operator. I suppose it was implemented for Counter because the values will always be integers so is a helpful shorthand.

Comment: @MattiJohn Oops. I meant to say Counters. Anyway, thanks for the explanation :)